# Push multiple objects at once

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

How can I do multiple object pushes at once with angularfire2?

Just pushing an array of objects doesn't set keys for each object.

```js
this.af.database.list('/symbols/').push({
  typ: "symbol1",
  // ....
});
this.af.database.list('/symbols/').push({
  typ: "symbol2",
  // ....
});
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With the regular Firebase JavaScript SDK, you can accomplish this with:

```
var updates = {};
updates['/symbols/'+ref.push().key] = {
  typ :"symbol1", ....
};
updates['/symbols/'+ref.push().key] = {
  typ :"symbol2", ....
};
ref.update(updates);
```

Since AngularFire2 is built on top of the normal Firebase JavaScript SDK, they interop perfectly. So you can just use the Firebase JavaScript SDK for this operation.

Comment: this does a server request with each `ref.push().key` ?

Comment: Nope. `push` is a client-side operation that generates a key that is statistically guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: "statistically guaranteed" 

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Frank's answer, improvised it to have a reducer and a promise resolver> Here is the final version:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const types = [
  {
    type: "symbol1"
  },
  {
    type: "symbol2"
  }
];
const rootRef = admin.database().ref();
const ref = rootRef.child(`/symbols`);

// prepare updates object based on types array.
let updates = types.reduce((update, type) => {
  let id = ref.push().key;
  update[`/symbols/${id}`] = type;
  return update;
}, {});

await rootRef.update(updates)
.then((response) => {
  return res.status(201).json({message: "Records added successfully"});
})
.catch((error)=>{
  res.sendStatus(500);
})
```